# Overload resolution failed?

Tags: three.js

[image]

I am trying to render a TTF Font Loader on a Plane using Promise and converting it to Texture then on the index.js mapping it on a MeshBasicMaterial but gives me the above error

The objective is to refract the text created below on a 3D transparent object, I am successful when I create the text on plain canvas filltext but want to use three.js fontloader, please can anyone let me know what the error might be caused by?

Much help would be appreciated.

Thank you

**fontloader.js**

```
const loader = new TTFLoader();
export default function loadFonts(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let font = null;
    let text = 'three.js';
    let group, textMesh1, textMesh2, textGeo, material;
    loader.load(url, function(json) {
      font = new THREE.Font(json);
      textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, {
        font: font,
        size: 70,
        height: 0,
        bevelThickness: 0,
        bevelSize: 0,
        bevelEnabled: false
      });
      textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
      textGeo.computeVertexNormals();
      const centerOffset = -0.5 * (textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x);
      textMesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(textGeo, material);
      textMesh1.position.x = centerOffset;
      textMesh1.position.y = 0;
      textMesh1.position.z = 0;
      textMesh1.rotation.x = 0;
      textMesh1.rotation.y = 0;
      var texture = new THREE.Texture(textMesh1);
      texture.needsUpdate = true;
      resolve(texture)
    });
  });
}
```

**index.js**

```
async createBackground() {
    // const tex = await loadTexture("test.JPG");
    const tex = await loadFonts("/fonts/kenpixel.ttf");
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: tex
    })
    material.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    const quad = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(), material);
    quad.layers.set(1);
    quad.scale.set(this.vp.width, this.vp.height, 1);
    return quad;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> var texture = new THREE.Texture(textMesh1);

This workflow is not supported. You can't use a mesh as the [image](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=texture#api/en/textures/Texture.image) of a texture.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and information, quite helpful for future termsa as well. Might there be way to make it a texture? or a way that I might be able to convert it to one?

Comment: You could render the mesh in some way into a render target and then use its `texture` property as a texture.